# Syslog is filling up the entire disk space with those entries

Tags: drivers

I just installed a fresh copy of ElementaryOS, and shortly after i did i get my / filesystem filled with large syslog and syslog.1 files the log files are filled with this entry

```
io.elementary.w[1638]: g_bytes_get_data: assertion 'bytes != NULL' failed
io.elementary.w[1638]: ((libnm-core/nm-utils.c:559)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
```

Currently i clear the log with cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog but i'm wondering how can i fix this error in the log files

Here is the output of lshw -c network

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 74:86:7a:5b:0e:a6
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0700000-c0700fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 34:23:87:16:18:3b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.100.200 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:c0600000-c067ffff memory:c0680000-c068ffff
```

And here is lscpi

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X]
```

My laptop model is

```
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Inspiron 5537
Version: A08
```

OS

```
elementary OS 6 Odin
```

Comment: This is something in the network manager that is failing repeatedly. Could you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c network` and `sudo lspci`? Knowing the brand and model of your computer along with the exact version of Elementary would be good, too. *Generally* this issue can be resolved with a driver swap, but it’s important to choose the correct driver. The additional details will make it more likely that you receive a complete answer 

Comment: @matigo I updated the questions as required, and while i get the general issue, i'm not clear on steps to try to solve this,
Thank you so much for your help,